# Python interpolation and extracting value of z for x and y?

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation, curve-fitting, curve, linear-interpolation

Would you please help
I have this data where z is a function for specific x and y

```
xs = [0.15, 0.35, 0.5, 0.67, 0.8]
ys = [0.01,0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
z = [0.75, 0.83, 1.00, 0.92, 0.91]
```

I arranged the values in this shape
How can I do interpolation for the points so I can call z value later different than the the one I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tck = interpolate.bisplrep(x, y, z, s=0)
def givemeZ(x,y):
    return interpolate.bisplev(x,y,tck)
```

Now by running the code, it will give z for specific x and y.
This can be used without plot. just put it under the values and make sure that the values are arranged in the same way

Answer (score 3):

A simple search would have helped already.
Your problem is basically the example of the 
[`scipy.interpolate.interp2d` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

xs = [ 0.15, 0.35, 0.5, 0.67, 0.8 ]
ys = [ 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ]
zz = np.array( [
    0.75, 0.83, 1.00, 0.92, 0.91,
    0.75, 0.82, 0.87, 0.88, 0.88,
    0.74, 0.81, 0.84, 0.83, 0.83,
    0.72, 0.76, 0.77, 0.76, 0.76,
    0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72 
    ] ).reshape( ( 5, 5 ) )

xx, yy = np.meshgrid( xs, ys )
f = interpolate.interp2d( xx, yy, zz, kind='cubic' )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1, projection='3d' )
ax.plot_surface( xx, yy, zz)

x2 = np.linspace( .15,.8,50 )
y2 = np.linspace( .01,.3,50 )

xx2, yy2 = np.meshgrid( x2, y2 )
zz2 = f( x2, y2 )

fig2 = plt.figure()
bx = fig2.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1, projection='3d' )
bx.plot_surface( xx2, yy2, zz2 )

plt.show()
```

providing the original data

[image: original data]

and the cubic interpolation on a 50 by 50 grid

[image: cubic interpolation]

Comment: @PrincessZena What did not work? Can you post the code of your try?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what i wanted is to get the value of z at specific x and y and my answer is below