# Surface triangulation and interpolation in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, interpolation, geospatial, triangulation

I have 3 lists of equal length of x, y and z coordinates.
With them, I need to triangulate a surface, and retrieve values that lie in a line over that surface. In other words, I need the values that lie on that surface that intersect a given plane.
Problem is, I have no idea where to start.
I have tried `scipy interp2d`, but it seems I need more z values them what I actually have (like shown in this answer: [Python interpolation and extracting value of z for x and y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201114/python-interpolation-and-extracting-value-of-z-for-x-and-y).

```
# this is the data I have
x = [0.0, 17.67599999997765, 49.08499999996275, 90.57299999985844, 136.60500000044703]
y = [0.0, 45.22349889159747, 66.50303846438841, 114.04427618243405, 187.7707039612985]
z = [0.0, 1.8700000000000045, 1.9539999999999509, 1.3929999999999154, 1.6299999999999955]
```

I need a final grid with x y z values that look something like this:
[image]

I don't really need too much resolution
My desired final result is to be able to retrieve specific values on top of that surface

Like the point line in this image:
[image]

I have also tried looking at geospatial libraries, but I couldn't find a solution either.

Maybe it's possible to interpolate the z values that I need? But I'm not really sure how to do this. I have never used scipy library before, and I'm still struggling to understand it.
I'm using python 3.9

Comment: Your data sample only has five points, but your graph shows perhaps 50.

Comment: That graph is only an illustration of what I need. I haven't been able to achieve that result yet

Comment: Please show the code you've used to interpolate, as well as the definition of your plane

Comment: That's exactly where the problem lies. I cannot figure out a code for interpolating this. I don't have a defining function. These are real x, y and height measurements. I've been trying to look for solutions in geospatial python libraries...
The defining plane is just one going from the lowest x,y coordinates, to the highest.

Comment: If you attempt to define an intersecting plane on x=y, you will never intersect any of the sample points that you have provided. "Lowest x,y coordinates to the highest" needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You barely have any data, so if you don't choose your intersecting plane carefully, you'll get no results back (or nonsense back). This includes the case of x=y; you can't do that at all - so the graph you've shown is entirely inapplicable to your data.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

x = [0.0, 17.6759999999776500, 49.0849999999627500,  90.5729999998584400, 136.6050000004470300]
y = [0.0, 45.2234988915974700, 66.5030384643884100, 114.0442761824340500, 187.7707039612985000]
z = [0.0,  1.8700000000000045,  1.9539999999999509,   1.3929999999999154,   1.6299999999999955]

xyi = np.empty((200, 2))
xyi[:, 0] = np.arange(200)
xyi[:, 1] = xyi[:, 0] * 1.374

zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata(
    points=(x, y), values=z,
    xi=xyi,
    method='cubic',
)

good_vals = ~np.isnan(zi)
xyz = np.empty((np.count_nonzero(good_vals), 3))
xyz[:, :2] = xyi[good_vals, :]
xyz[:, 2] = zi[good_vals]
print(xyz)
```

```
[[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.37400000e+00 4.68988354e-02]
 [2.00000000e+00 2.74800000e+00 9.44855957e-02]
 [3.00000000e+00 4.12200000e+00 1.42698116e-01]
 [4.00000000e+00 5.49600000e+00 1.91474231e-01]
 [5.00000000e+00 6.87000000e+00 2.40751776e-01]
 [6.00000000e+00 8.24400000e+00 2.90468585e-01]
 [7.00000000e+00 9.61800000e+00 3.40562494e-01]
 [8.00000000e+00 1.09920000e+01 3.90971337e-01]
 [9.00000000e+00 1.23660000e+01 4.41632950e-01]
 [1.00000000e+01 1.37400000e+01 4.92485168e-01]
 [1.10000000e+01 1.51140000e+01 5.43465824e-01]
 [1.20000000e+01 1.64880000e+01 5.94512755e-01]
 [1.30000000e+01 1.78620000e+01 6.45563795e-01]
 [1.40000000e+01 1.92360000e+01 6.96556779e-01]
 [1.50000000e+01 2.06100000e+01 7.47429542e-01]
 [1.60000000e+01 2.19840000e+01 7.98119919e-01]
 [1.70000000e+01 2.33580000e+01 8.48565744e-01]
 [1.80000000e+01 2.47320000e+01 8.98704854e-01]
 [1.90000000e+01 2.61060000e+01 9.48475082e-01]
 [2.00000000e+01 2.74800000e+01 9.97814263e-01]
 [2.10000000e+01 2.88540000e+01 1.04666023e+00]
 [2.20000000e+01 3.02280000e+01 1.09495083e+00]
 [2.30000000e+01 3.16020000e+01 1.14262388e+00]
 [2.40000000e+01 3.29760000e+01 1.18961722e+00]
 [2.50000000e+01 3.43500000e+01 1.23586870e+00]
 [2.60000000e+01 3.57240000e+01 1.28131613e+00]
 [2.70000000e+01 3.70980000e+01 1.32589737e+00]
 [2.80000000e+01 3.84720000e+01 1.36955024e+00]
 [2.90000000e+01 3.98460000e+01 1.41221257e+00]
 [3.00000000e+01 4.12200000e+01 1.45382221e+00]
 [3.10000000e+01 4.25940000e+01 1.49431699e+00]
 [3.20000000e+01 4.39680000e+01 1.53363474e+00]
 [3.30000000e+01 4.53420000e+01 1.57171329e+00]
 [3.40000000e+01 4.67160000e+01 1.60849049e+00]
 [3.50000000e+01 4.80900000e+01 1.64390417e+00]
 [3.60000000e+01 4.94640000e+01 1.67789216e+00]
 [3.70000000e+01 5.08380000e+01 1.71039230e+00]
 [3.80000000e+01 5.22120000e+01 1.74134241e+00]
 [3.90000000e+01 5.35860000e+01 1.77068035e+00]
 [4.00000000e+01 5.49600000e+01 1.79834394e+00]
 [4.10000000e+01 5.63340000e+01 1.82427101e+00]
 [4.20000000e+01 5.77080000e+01 1.84839941e+00]
 [4.30000000e+01 5.90820000e+01 1.87066696e+00]
 [4.40000000e+01 6.04560000e+01 1.89101151e+00]
 [4.50000000e+01 6.18300000e+01 1.90937088e+00]
 [4.60000000e+01 6.32040000e+01 1.92570604e+00]
 [4.70000000e+01 6.45780000e+01 1.94056076e+00]
 [4.80000000e+01 6.59520000e+01 1.95421968e+00]
 [4.90000000e+01 6.73260000e+01 1.96719695e+00]
 [5.00000000e+01 6.87000000e+01 1.97928362e+00]
 [5.10000000e+01 7.00740000e+01 1.98942207e+00]
 [5.20000000e+01 7.14480000e+01 1.99700320e+00]
 [5.30000000e+01 7.28220000e+01 2.00180807e+00]
 [5.40000000e+01 7.41960000e+01 2.00361776e+00]
 [5.50000000e+01 7.55700000e+01 2.00221333e+00]
 [5.60000000e+01 7.69440000e+01 1.99737586e+00]
 [5.70000000e+01 7.83180000e+01 1.98888640e+00]
 [5.80000000e+01 7.96920000e+01 1.97652604e+00]
 [5.90000000e+01 8.10660000e+01 1.96007583e+00]
 [6.00000000e+01 8.24400000e+01 1.93931685e+00]
 [6.10000000e+01 8.38140000e+01 1.91403017e+00]
 [6.20000000e+01 8.51880000e+01 1.88497097e+00]
 [6.30000000e+01 8.65620000e+01 1.85740456e+00]
 [6.40000000e+01 8.79360000e+01 1.83466390e+00]
 [6.50000000e+01 8.93100000e+01 1.81970145e+00]
 [6.60000000e+01 9.06840000e+01 1.81546971e+00]
 [6.70000000e+01 9.20580000e+01 1.82177337e+00]
 [6.80000000e+01 9.34320000e+01 1.82842946e+00]
 [6.90000000e+01 9.48060000e+01 1.83439551e+00]
 [7.00000000e+01 9.61800000e+01 1.83969621e+00]
 [7.10000000e+01 9.75540000e+01 1.84435625e+00]
 [7.20000000e+01 9.89280000e+01 1.84840034e+00]
 [7.30000000e+01 1.00302000e+02 1.85185316e+00]
 [7.40000000e+01 1.01676000e+02 1.85473940e+00]
 [7.50000000e+01 1.03050000e+02 1.85708377e+00]
 [7.60000000e+01 1.04424000e+02 1.85891096e+00]
 [7.70000000e+01 1.05798000e+02 1.86024566e+00]
 [7.80000000e+01 1.07172000e+02 1.86111256e+00]
 [7.90000000e+01 1.08546000e+02 1.86153636e+00]
 [8.00000000e+01 1.09920000e+02 1.86154176e+00]
 [8.10000000e+01 1.11294000e+02 1.86115344e+00]
 [8.20000000e+01 1.12668000e+02 1.86039610e+00]
 [8.30000000e+01 1.14042000e+02 1.85929444e+00]
 [8.40000000e+01 1.15416000e+02 1.85787402e+00]
 [8.50000000e+01 1.16790000e+02 1.85624017e+00]
 [8.60000000e+01 1.18164000e+02 1.85445481e+00]
 [8.70000000e+01 1.19538000e+02 1.85252055e+00]
 [8.80000000e+01 1.20912000e+02 1.85043999e+00]
 [8.90000000e+01 1.22286000e+02 1.84821574e+00]
 [9.00000000e+01 1.23660000e+02 1.84585039e+00]
 [9.10000000e+01 1.25034000e+02 1.84334656e+00]
 [9.20000000e+01 1.26408000e+02 1.84070685e+00]
 [9.30000000e+01 1.27782000e+02 1.83793385e+00]
 [9.40000000e+01 1.29156000e+02 1.83503019e+00]
 [9.50000000e+01 1.30530000e+02 1.83199845e+00]
 [9.60000000e+01 1.31904000e+02 1.82884125e+00]
 [9.70000000e+01 1.33278000e+02 1.82556119e+00]
 [9.80000000e+01 1.34652000e+02 1.82216087e+00]
 [9.90000000e+01 1.36026000e+02 1.81864290e+00]
 [1.00000000e+02 1.37400000e+02 1.81500988e+00]
 [1.01000000e+02 1.38774000e+02 1.81126441e+00]
 [1.02000000e+02 1.40148000e+02 1.80740911e+00]
 [1.03000000e+02 1.41522000e+02 1.80344657e+00]
 [1.04000000e+02 1.42896000e+02 1.79937940e+00]
 [1.05000000e+02 1.44270000e+02 1.79521020e+00]
 [1.06000000e+02 1.45644000e+02 1.79094157e+00]
 [1.07000000e+02 1.47018000e+02 1.78657613e+00]
 [1.08000000e+02 1.48392000e+02 1.78211648e+00]
 [1.09000000e+02 1.49766000e+02 1.77756521e+00]
 [1.10000000e+02 1.51140000e+02 1.77292494e+00]
 [1.11000000e+02 1.52514000e+02 1.76819827e+00]
 [1.12000000e+02 1.53888000e+02 1.76338780e+00]
 [1.13000000e+02 1.55262000e+02 1.75849613e+00]
 [1.14000000e+02 1.56636000e+02 1.75352588e+00]
 [1.15000000e+02 1.58010000e+02 1.74847964e+00]
 [1.16000000e+02 1.59384000e+02 1.74336002e+00]
 [1.17000000e+02 1.60758000e+02 1.73816962e+00]
 [1.18000000e+02 1.62132000e+02 1.73291105e+00]
 [1.19000000e+02 1.63506000e+02 1.72758692e+00]
 [1.20000000e+02 1.64880000e+02 1.72219982e+00]
 [1.21000000e+02 1.66254000e+02 1.71675236e+00]
 [1.22000000e+02 1.67628000e+02 1.71124714e+00]
 [1.23000000e+02 1.69002000e+02 1.70568677e+00]
 [1.24000000e+02 1.70376000e+02 1.70007386e+00]
 [1.25000000e+02 1.71750000e+02 1.69441100e+00]
 [1.26000000e+02 1.73124000e+02 1.68870081e+00]
 [1.27000000e+02 1.74498000e+02 1.68294588e+00]
 [1.28000000e+02 1.75872000e+02 1.67714882e+00]
 [1.29000000e+02 1.77246000e+02 1.67131224e+00]
 [1.30000000e+02 1.78620000e+02 1.66543873e+00]
 [1.31000000e+02 1.79994000e+02 1.65953091e+00]
 [1.32000000e+02 1.81368000e+02 1.65359138e+00]
 [1.33000000e+02 1.82742000e+02 1.64762273e+00]
 [1.34000000e+02 1.84116000e+02 1.64162758e+00]
 [1.35000000e+02 1.85490000e+02 1.63560853e+00]
 [1.36000000e+02 1.86864000e+02 1.62956819e+00]]
```